# Custom Model not getting methods from included module

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I have a custom model called Like which looks like this:

```
class Like
    include LikeRedis

    attr_reader :user_id

    def initialize(attributes)
        @user_id = attributes[:user_id]
    end

    def self.for_medium(medium)
        get_likes(medium).map { |like| Like.new(like: {user_id: like.to_i}) }
    end

end
```

And in `app/models/concerns/` I have like_redis.rb

which looks like this:

```
module LikeRedis
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    ...

    def get_likes(medium)
        $redis.smembers("medium:#{medium.id}:#{:likes}")
    end
end
```

Now if I want to use the `get_like` method I have, rails throws this error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `get_likes' for Like:Class
```

I tried other methods too in the file and none of them worked, it's as if the `include LikeRedis` does not work at all.

What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, like you are trying to call `Like.get_likes(medium)`, but the way you have defined it, expects you to have an instance of `Like` class and call it on on the instance

```
like = Like.new
like.get_likes(medium)
```

If you want the code to work, you need to, define your method the following way:

```
module LikeRedis
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  ...

  def self.get_likes(medium)
    $redis.smembers("medium:#{medium.id}:#{:likes}")
  end
end
```